# Does cloudflare site http://1.1.1.1/ have any http endpoint that returns the visitor's internet ip address?

Tags: http, ip, cloudflare

Like what http://httpbin.org/ip returns, does cloudflare site http://1.1.1.1/ have any similar http endpoint that returns the visitor's internet ip address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://1.1.1.1/cdn-cgi/trace

The 3rd line typically reads `ip=ex.a.mp.le`, go parse it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an IP geolocation API for this purpose. It has the benefit to include many data related to the visitor IP, in addition to the IP address. Here is an example:

https://api.ipregistry.co/?key=tryout&pretty=true